# JSDoc: Node.js require statement replaces class definition

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

In my Node.js project, I have normal class definitions like:

```
/**
 * My awesome class.
 * @constructor
 */
var MyClass = function MyClass() {}
```

And in another file I require it like:

```
var MyClass = require('./myclass.js').MyClass;
```

But sometimes JSDoc finds the require statement and only documents MyClass as a global variable.  How to make JSDoc always document the class definition and ignore the variables defined in require statements?

Comment: which variables do you mean? do you have `var MyClass = require(...).MyClass` surrounded by comments?

Comment: MyClass is defined it its main file, then used in other files in the "require" section. For example:

Comment: For example: `var SomeClass = require(...).SomeClass; var MyClass = require(...).MyClass; var AnotherClass = require(...).AnotherClass;`